# StringEcapeUtils not working for &#149;

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash

I have a HTML string stored in Database like below

```
1&#149;DAY Brand<sup>&#174;</sup>Brand<sup>&#174;</sup>details&#151;\r\n<BR>\r\n<BR>\r\n<p>This Brand® is the best for you needs. Plus our Water® Technology is more comfort for you. Brand® offers the best in class mileage./p>\r\n<UL>   \r\n    <LI>Brand® is the #1 selling brand globally.\r\n    <LI>Experience all-day comfort with Water® Technology.\r\n  <LI>One of the highest levels of Mileage available in fuel.\r\n</UL>
```

I am reading this string from Database in Spring Batch job and creating a json file with structure like `"string":"value"` where my value is whole string which I provided above.

Now using logstash I am trying to Push this json into Elasticsearch.When i do this I am getting below Error `exception=>#<LogStash::Json::ParserError: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xae` because of string `®` so in java while constructing json file i tried using `org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4()` to escape char `®` but since i have `&#149; &#174;` in my string it is getting generated like `&amp;#149; &amp;#174 and for ® it is coming like &reg;`, now when i use this html in browser this string is not gettign displayed as expected. so i thought in java first i will use `org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(ofMyString)` so that my string will get generated like

```
1DAY Brand<sup>®</sup>Brand<sup>®</sup>details<BR><BR><p>This Brand® is the best for you needs. Plus our Water® Technology is more comfort for you. Brand® offers the best in class mileage./p><UL>     <LI>Brand® is the #1 selling brand globally.    <LI>Experience all-day comfort with Water® Technology.  <LI>One of the highest levels of Mileage available in fuel.</UL>
```

and again i will use escapeHtml4() to resolve this issue. But this is not working. Issue I am facing here is when i do this `.` which is `&#149;` is not displayed in html in browser. also alignment is missing.
PFB Logstash script:

```
input{    file
{
    path => ["C:/input.json"]
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
}}filter{
mutate
{
    replace => [ "message", "%{message}" ]
    gsub => [ 'message','\n','']
}
json { source => message }
mutate{
    remove_field => ["message"]
}}output {
   elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            index => "index"
            document_type => "type"
            document_id => "%{id}"
   }
   stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Can somebody please help.

Comment: Have you tried to just call `replaceAll("®", "&reg;")` on your string when constructing your JSON?

Comment: I tried that,it was working, but i am not sure how many such characters will be there

Comment: How did those strings get stored in your database in the first place?

Comment: @Val We have a Content management system which stores these string in database. This string is constructed by business users which we cannot control

Comment: Ok then since those strings contain both escaped and unescaped entities, I'd say that your approach of first unescaping and then escaping again is the right one. Have you tried `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4`?